# RSPEC test fail, app works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following rails tutorial and would like some help with RSPEC errors.

**Errors:**

```
1) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should be successful
     Failure/Error: Factory(:user, :name => Factory.next(:name),
     RuntimeError:
       No such sequence: name
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23:in `times'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23

 2) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should have an element for each user
 Failure/Error: Factory(:user, :name => Factory.next(:name),
 RuntimeError:
   No such sequence: name
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23:in `times'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23

  3) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should paginate users
 Failure/Error: Factory(:user, :name => Factory.next(:name),
 RuntimeError:
   No such sequence: name
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23:in `times'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23

  4) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should have delete links for admins
 Failure/Error: Factory(:user, :name => Factory.next(:name),
 RuntimeError:
   No such sequence: name
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23:in `times'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23

  5) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should not have delete links for non-admins
 Failure/Error: Factory(:user, :name => Factory.next(:name),
 RuntimeError:
   No such sequence: name
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:24
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23:in `times'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23
```

**UPDATE: These errors did not go away! **

```
  6) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' as an admin user should redirect to the users page
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(users_path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/1>.
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:287

  7) User has_password? method should be true if the passwords match
 Failure/Error: @user.has_password?(@attr[:password]).should be_true
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_password?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:103

  8) User has_password? method should be false if the passwords don't match
 Failure/Error: @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_password?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:107

  9) FriendlyForwardings should forward to the requested page after signin
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template('users/edit')
   expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <"layouts/_footer, layouts/application,     layouts/_stylesheets, users/show, sessions/new, layouts/_header">
     # ./spec/requests/friendly_forwardings_spec.rb:11
```

**User Controller Spec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'index'" do

  describe "for non-signed-in users" do
    it "should deny access" do
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
      flash[:notice].should =~ /sign in/i
    end
  end

  describe "for signed-in users" do

    before(:each) do
            @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
            second = Factory(:user, :name => "Bob", :email => "another@example.com")
            third  = Factory(:user, :name => "Ben", :email => "another@example.net")

            30.times do
              Factory(:user, :name => Factory.next(:name),
                             :email => Factory.next(:email))
      end 
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have an element for each user" do
      get :index
      User.paginate(:page => 1).each do |user|
        response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
      end
    end

    it "should paginate users" do
      get :index
      response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
      response.should have_selector("span.disabled", :content => "Previous")
      response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2",
                                                 :content => "2")
      response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2",
                                                 :content => "Next")
    end

    it "should have delete links for admins" do
      @user.toggle!(:admin)
      other_user = User.all.second
      get :index
      response.should have_selector('a', :href => user_path(other_user),
                                        :content => "delete")
    end

    it "should not have delete links for non-admins" do
        other_user = User.all.second
        get :index
        response.should_not have_selector('a', :href => user_path(other_user),
                                                :content => "delete")
    end
  end
  end 

  describe "GET 'show'" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end

it "should be successful" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should be_success
end

it "should find the right user" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  assigns(:user).should == @user
end

it "should include the user's name" do
     get :show, :id => @user
     response.should have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)
end

it "should have a profile image" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
end
  end

  describe "GET 'new'" do

it "should be successful" do
  get :new
  response.should be_success
end
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do

describe "failure" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "" }
  end

  it "should render the 'new' page" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    response.should render_template('new')
  end


  it "should not create a user" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :user => @attr
    end.should_not change(User, :count)
  end
end 


describe "success" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "New User", :email => "user@example.com", :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password" }
  end 

  it "should create a user" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :user => @attr
    end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
  end 

  it "should have a welcome message" do
          post :create, :user => @attr
          flash[:success].should =~ /Welcome to Sample App/i
  end

  it "should sign the user in" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    controller.should be_signed_in
  end 
end
  end 

  describe "PUT 'update'" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  test_sign_in(@user)
end

describe "failure" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :email => "", :name => "", :password => "", :password_cofirmation => "" }
  end 

  it "should render the 'edit' page" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    response.should render_template('edit')
  end
end  

describe "success" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "New Name", :email => "user@example.org", :password => "newpassword", :password_confirmation => "newpassword" }
  end

  it "should change the user's attributes" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    @user.reload
    @user.name.should == @attr[:name]
    @user.email.should == @attr[:email]
  end 

  it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
  end 

  it "should have a flash message" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
  end 
end 
  end 

  describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end

describe "for non-signed-in users" do

  it "should deny access to 'edit'" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
  end

  it "should deny access to 'update'" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
  end
    end

    describe "for signed-in users" do

  before(:each) do
    wrong_user = Factory(:user, :email => "user@example.net")
    test_sign_in(wrong_user)
  end

  it "should require matching users for 'edit'" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end

  it "should require matching users for 'update'" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
  end

  describe "GET 'edit'" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  test_sign_in(@user)
end

it "should be successful" do
  get :edit, :id => @user
  response.should be_success
end

it "should have a link to change the Gravatar" do
  get :edit, :id => @user
  gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/emails"
  response.should have_selector("a", :href => gravatar_url, :content => "change")
end
  end

  describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  describe "as a non-signed-in user" do
    it "should deny access" do
      delete :destroy, :id => @user
      response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
    end
  end

  describe "as a non-admin user" do
    it "should protect the page" do
      test_sign_in(@user)
      delete :destroy, :id => @user
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
    end
      end

      describe "as an admin user" do

    before(:each) do
      admin = Factory(:user, :email => "admin@example.com", :admin => true)
      test_sign_in(admin)
    end

    it "should destroy the user" do
      lambda do
        delete :destroy, :id => @user
      end.should change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

         it "should redirect to the users page" do
      delete :destroy, :id => @user
      flash[:success].should =~ /destroyed/i
      response.should redirect_to(users_path)
    end
  end
  end
end
```

**User Spec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com", :password =>     "password", :password_confirmation => "password" }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attribute" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end 

  it "should require a name" do
    no_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => ""))
    no_name_user.should_not be_valid
  end 

  it "should require an email address" do
     no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
     no_email_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject names that are too long" do
    long_name = "a" *51
    long_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => long_name))
    long_name_user.should_not be_valid
  end 

  it "should accept valid email addresses" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo.com THE_USER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp]
        addresses.each do |address|
          valid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
          valid_email_user.should be_valid
        end
  end


  it "should reject invalid email addresses" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
       addresses.each do |address|
          invalid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
          invalid_email_user.should_not be_valid
      end
  end     

  it "should reject duplicate email addresses" do
      # Put a user with given email address into the database.
      User.create!(@attr)
      user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
      user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject email addresses idential up to the case" do
    upcased_email = @attr[:email].upcase
    User.create!(@attr.merge(:email => upcased_email))
    user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
    user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
      end 

  describe "password validations" do

it "should require a password" do
  User.new(@attr.merge(:password => "", :password_confirmation => "")).
    should_not be_valid
end 

it "should require a matching password confirmation" do
  User.new(@attr.merge(:password_confirmation => "invalid")).
    should_not be_valid
end

it "should reject short passwords" do
  short = "a" * 5
  hash = @attr.merge(:password => short, :password_confirmation => short)
  User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
end

 it "should reject long passwords" do
    long = "a" * 41
    hash = @attr.merge(:password => long, :password_confirmation => long)
    User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
 end
  end

  describe "password encryption" do

before(:each) do
  @user = User.create!(@attr)
end 

it "should set the encrypted password attribute" do
  @user.encrypted_password.should_not be_blank 
end 

it "should have an encrypted password attribute" do
  @user.should respond_to(:encrypted_password)
end
  end

  describe "has_password? method" do

  it "should be true if the passwords match" do
    @user.has_password?(@attr[:password]).should be_true
  end

  it "should be false if the passwords don't match" do
    @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
  end 
  end

  describe "authenticate method" do

  it "should return nil on email/password mismatch" do
    wrong_password_user = User.authenticate(@attr[:email], "wrongpass")
    wrong_password_user.should be_nil
  end 

  it "should return nil for an email address with no user" do
    nonexistent_user = User.authenticate("email@example.com", @attr[:password])
    nonexistent_user.should be_nil
  end 

  it "should return the user on email/password match" do
    matching_user = User.authenticate(@attr[:email], @attr[:password])
    matching_user.should == @user
  end 
  end 

  describe "admin attribute" do

before(:each) do
     @user = User.create!(@attr)
end

it "should respond to admin" do
  @user.should respond_to(:admin)
end

it "should not be an admin by default" do
  @user.should_not be_admin
end

it "should be convertible to an admin" do
  @user.toggle!(:admin)
  @user.should be_admin
end
end 
end
```

**Friendly Forwarding Spec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "FriendlyForwardings" do

  it "should forward to the requested page after signin" do
    user = Factory(:user)
    visit edit_user_path(user)
    fill_in :email,    :with => user.email
    fill_in :password, :with => user.password
    click_button
    response.should render_template('users/edit')
    visit signout_path
    visit signin_path
    fill_in :email,    :with => user.email
    fill_in :password, :with => user.password
    click_button
    response.should render_template('users/show')
  end
end
```

**Factories:**

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Michael Hartl"
  user.email                 "mhartl@example.com"
  user.password              "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end

Factory.sequence :email do |n|
  "person-#{n}@example.com"
end
```

Comment: I've found from experience it can be pretty easy to make a small typo that does this when following a tutorial. If you can download the complete source code, try using a compare tool like BeyondCompare to check your code against the source in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your factory.rb something like

```
Factory.sequence :name do |n|
  "person-#{n}"
end
```

Comment: heh, in your tests you ask for :name sequence, but define :email sequence

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? I am new to rails.

Comment: @jsttn: You say "Already done", but the code you posted for your factories only includes a generator for `:email`, not `:name`.

Comment: I am too :)
If you want use Factory.next(:name) you need define sequence generator in factory.rb like i say. You define only :email sequence generator